# Pop up Modal for Image that can be zoom in/out

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I don't know how to achieve this. Maybe someone has a good example on how to create a pop up modal for an image where it can be zoom in and out? I'm using asp.net and vb.net for ui and coding. But I haven't done any pop up modal so I have no idea.

Comment: Are you looking to just popup a zoomed (larger) image when clicked on, or are you looking for when you pop the image + dialog, they can zoom that image in the popup? I mean, the 1st is dead simple, the 2nd option of being able to change/zoom the image you are looking at is quite a different question. So, having some small images, and clicking on one image to popup a nice big zoomed image? (easy).  To pop up a image with zoom ability AFTER it been displayed is quite difficult. Which are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the 2nd option where you pop up an image then you can zoom in and out. That is my plan but as you said it's hard. so maybe just a pop up modal for the image. Can you point out an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for a simple image zoom, then we can have this gridview with some Images:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' Width="140" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdView_Click"
                    Style="margin-top: 20px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

After above, we will use a jquery.UI dialog. So, we assume you have both jQuery, and jQuery.UI installed.

So, we need a "div" area on the page that the jQuery.UI dialog will pop.

So, then after GridView above, we have this:

```
        <div id="imagepop" runat="server" style="display: none; text-align: center; height: 80%">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFighterName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="FighterImage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                Width="80%" Height="90%" />
        </div>


        <script>

            function popimage(btn) {

                pHeight = ($(window).height() * 0.96)
                pWidth = ($(window).width() * 0.80)

                myDialog = $("#imagepop");
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Fighter",
                    modal: true,
                    height: pHeight,
                    width: pWidth,
                    closeText: "",
                    show: "fade",
                    buttons: {

                        Ok: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog("close")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
```

The code behind to load the GridView is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRst("SELECT * FROM Fighters")
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

And the simple "view" button in the GridView when clicked has this code:

```
Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    lblFighterName.Text = gRow.Cells(0).Text

    Dim RowImage As Image = gRow.FindControl("Image2")
    FighterImage.ImageUrl = RowImage.ImageUrl

    Dim sJava As String = "popimage()"

    ' now pop our dialog to display the zoomed in image
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "MyPop", sJava, True)


End Sub
```

and the result is thus this:

[image]

So, popping a image when clicked on, rather easy.

If you need some kind of zoom in that dialog, then some searching for a JavaScript zoom library would be required.

Do keep in mind that if you do display that popup image, user's can use the ctrl-mouse wheel to zoom in/out.

## Edit: Without a GridView

The code is actually going to be the same, and the button in the GridView was just a regular button.

So, say we have this Image and a button:

```
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
            ImageUrl="../Content/Fighters/f35.jpg"
            Width="200px" Height="155px"
            />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdPop" runat="server" Text="View Image"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdPop_Click" />

        <div id="imagepop" runat="server" style="display: none; text-align: center; height: 80%">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFighterName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="FighterImage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                Width="80%" Height="90%" />
        </div>


        <script>
            function popimage(btn) {

                pHeight = ($(window).height() * 0.96)
                pWidth = ($(window).width() * 0.80)

                myDialog = $("#imagepop");
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Fighter",
                    modal: true,
                    height: pHeight,
                    width: pWidth,
                    closeText: "",
                    show: "fade",
                    buttons: {

                        Ok: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog("close")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
```

And the code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdPop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    FighterImage.ImageUrl = Image1.ImageUrl

    Dim sJava As String = "popimage()"
    ' now pop our dialog to display the zoomed in image
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "MyPop", sJava, True)

End Sub
```

In fact, in this case, we could use 100% client side code, but either way, the result is now this:

[image]

## Edit: You have to include jQuery, and jQuery.UI

As I noted, you require jQuery. jQuery is installed by default for most standard templates, but jQuery.UI is not.

So, to eliminate this issue, then try this markup:

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
            ImageUrl="../Content/Fighters/f35.jpg"
            Width="200px" Height="155px"
            />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdPop" runat="server" Text="View Image"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdPop_Click" />

        <div id="imagepop" runat="server" style="display: none; text-align: center; height: 80%">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFighterName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="FighterImage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                Width="80%" Height="90%" />
        </div>


        <script>
            function popimage(btn) {

                pHeight = ($(window).height() * 0.96)
                pWidth = ($(window).width() * 0.80)

                myDialog = $("#imagepop");
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Fighter",
                    modal: true,
                    height: pHeight,
                    width: pWidth,
                    closeText: "",
                    show: "slide",
                    buttons: {

                        Ok: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog("close")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Do you have a simple example without the grid view? Like the modal and button only?

Comment: It is actually the same code, but see my edit with just a image and a button. As noted, since we not really using a GridView, then such code could be 100% client side JavaScript, but at the end of the day here, it is the "concept" of how this works, and how this works is the same for the GridView and a button, or if you just have a image and a button.

Comment: I tried your code, I don't know but it's just not working on me.

Comment: As noted, it is assumed you know what jQuery and jQuery.UI is, and as I noted, you need both for this to work. See my new and additional edit, you should be able to create a blank new page, and cut + paste the code.

Comment: Yup, I installed the jquery from NuGet but it's not that. I think the way I called the script. I just tested yours as is. It's working. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you have an idea why would  the pop up won't show? I've tested your code on a separate solution, so I know your code works. But when I try to put it on the real project I have it doesn't work. Is there a setting I should do?

Comment: In every web page that will use jQuery, jQuery.UI and the css style sheet for jQuery.UI? You need the 3 references in that example that works. They can be external references (often called CDN = content delivery network), or you can NuGet and download jQuery, and jQuery.UI to your local computer, but EVEN in that case you STILL must always and in EVERY case include the script references in the given web page for such code to work. So, just using Nuget to download the script libaries will not work alone - the scripts and css must ALWAYS be included in the given web paged.